# PowerShell Script - Run multiple executables in parallel and wait for all launched executables to terminate before proceeding

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, start-process, start-job

I have an executable file (.exe) which has to be run multiple times with different arguments in parallel (ideally on different cores) from a PowerShell script, and at the end wait for all launched executables to terminate. To implement that in my PowerShell script I have used the `Start-Job` command that runs multiple threads in parallel. And as the script needs to wait for all jobs to finish their execution I used `Start-Job` in the combination with `Get-Job | Wait-Job`. This makes the script wait for all of the jobs running in the session to finish:

```
$SCRIPT_PATH = "path/to/Program.exe"
$jobs = Get-ChildItem -Path $DIR | Foreach-Object {

    if ($_ -like "Folder") { 
        # Do nothing 
    }
    else {

        $ARG1_VAR = "Directory\$($_.BaseName)"
        $ARG2_VAR = "Directory\$($_.BaseName)\SubDirectory"
        $ARG3_VAR = "Directory\$($_.BaseName)\SubSubDirectory"

        if (Test-Path -Path $ARG1_VAR)
        {
            Start-Job -Name -ScriptBlock {
               & $using:SCRIPT_PATH -arg1 $using:ARG1_VAR -arg2 $using:ARG2_VAR
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Start-Job -Name -ScriptBlock {
                & $using:SCRIPT_PATH -arg1 $using:ARG1_VAR -arg3 $using:ARG3_VAR
             }
        }
    }
}

$jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

However, it seems that `-FilePath` argument of `Start-Job` does NOT accept `.exe` files, but only `.ps1` files, and therefore I get an exception.

Thus, I decided to use `Start-Process` command instead which spawns seperate processes instead of seperate threads. But I was not able to find a command that can wait for the termination of all started processed from my script. Therefore, I tried to do it manually by storing all started processes in an array list. And then I tried to wait for each process (using process ID) to terminate. However, that does not seem to work either, because `Start-Process -FilePath Program.exe -ArgumentList $ARG_LIST` returns NULL, and therefore nothing is saved in the `$Process_List.`

```
$SCRIPT_PATH = "path/to/Program.exe"
$procs = Get-ChildItem -Path $DIR | Foreach-Object {

    if ($_ -like "Folder") { 
        # Do nothing 
    }
    else {

        $ARG1_VAR = "Directory\$($_.BaseName)"
        $ARG2_VAR = "Directory\$($_.BaseName)\SubDirectory"
        $ARG3_VAR = "Directory\$($_.BaseName)\SubSubDirectory"

        if (Test-Path -Path $ARG1_VAR)
        {
            $ARG_LIST = @( "-arg1 $ARG1_VAR", "-arg2 $ARG2_VAR")

            Start-Process -FilePath $SCRIPT_PATH -ArgumentList $ARG_LIST -PassThru -NoNewWindow
        }
        else
        {
            
            $ARG_LIST = @( "-arg1 $ARG1_VAR", "-arg3 $ARG3_VAR")

            Start-Process -FilePath $SCRIPT_PATH -ArgumentList $ARG_LIST -PassThru -NoNewWindow
        }
    }
}

$procs | Wait-Process
```

I would appreciate any help. Please note I am using Powershell 5.1, thus `ForEach-Object -Parallel`construct is not supported on my machine.

Thank you!

Comment: So, on the last code snippet, you're using `Start-Process` yet for waiting for them, you're using `Receive-Job` which is wrong. Process and Jobs are not the same, use `Wait-Process` instead for waiting for Processes

Comment: The first code snippet looks correct, I don't see anything wrong with it. You could ask a new question with that code snippet specifically to troubleshoot it

Comment: Regarding the 2nd code snippet. Sorry I posted the wrong code. That was a copy-paste mistake and I corrected it now. I was using `$procs | Wait-Process` in my code actually.

Comment: Now after the update, both snippets looks correct to me. I don't see nothing wrong with them

Comment: I have tried to output both string `"$procs"` as well as non-string `$procs`. The string `"$procs"`  outputs `System.Object[]` whereas `$procs` lists correct content (process name, ID, etc.) of all started processes.
Therefore, the variable `$procs` seems to be filled correctly. However, is actually `System.Object[]` the correct data type to be passed to `$procs | Wait-Process` ? Shouldn't the data type look something like `System.Diagnostics.Process[]` instead of `System.Object[]`?
Exception message says: _Wait-Process : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters of the command …_

Comment: `Object[]` is correct, `Wait-Process` has no problem with that, for example: `$procs = 0..2 | %{ Start-Process powershell.exe -PassThru }; $procs | Wait-Process` 3 pwsh processes will appear and you'll see the main thread waiting for them. After closing the 3 pwsh processes you will regain control of the main thread.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. Then I have no other idea why `$procs | Wait-Process` does not work in my case.

Comment: ‍♂️ the issue is `-NoNewWindow` most likely. Remove it and try

Comment: The behaviour unforunately stays same after removing `-NoNewWindow`. Could it be due to PowerShell version I am using? I am using V5.1.

Comment: No, it should work properly in 5.1. My advise would be to ask a new question to see if someone else can spot anything wrong but as you have it right both codes looks correct to me to be honest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first example with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2), instead of using the `-FilePath` parameter you could use the `-ScriptBlock` parameter:

```bash
$path = 'path/to/my.exe'
$jobs = Get-ChildItem -Path $DIR | Foreach-Object {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        & $using:path -arg1 $using:_ -arg2 $using:ARG2_VAR
    }
}
$jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Regarding your second example, using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2) you should note that, this cmdlet [**produces no output without the `-PassThru` switch**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2#outputs), hence you're adding effectively nothing to your list.

```bash
$processes = Get-ChildItem -Path $DIR | Foreach-Object {
    Start-Process -FilePath Program.exe -ArgumentList $ARG_LIST -PassThru
}
```

With this minor addition of the `-PassThru` switch you can either use a [`while` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while?view=powershell-7.2) checking the [`.HasExited` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited?view=net-6.0#system-diagnostics-process-hasexited) of the objects in case you need to do something else with your code while waiting for the processes:

```bash
# block the thread until all processes have finished
while($processes.HasExited -contains $false) {
    # do something else here if needed
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}
```

Or even simpler, as [mklement0 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72873463/poweshell-script-run-multiple-executables-in-parallel-and-wait-for-all-ran-exe/72873704?noredirect=1#comment128717401_72873704), if you only need to wait for the processes, you can use [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process?view=powershell-7.2):

```bash
$processes | Wait-Process
```

Comment: Thank you the good comment. I have tried to use both of the versions you have provided, one with `Start-Job` and other with `Start-Process`. Somehow, passing the same arguments to those 2 PS-Commands produces different outcome. Namely when I use `Start-Job` the executable is launched, and it finishes its execution, but somehow the executable does not create an output file that it is supposed to create. Whereas `Start-Process` creates the file successfuly. For my job, I used `Wait-Job -Job $job` to wait for job to end. But that should not influence the behaviour from my understanding?

Comment: One more comment: `$processes | Wait-Process` throws an exception in my case. It looks like `$processes` is empty after executing `$processes = Get-ChildItem -Path $DIR | Foreach-Object`. I think that is because I am calling `Start-Process` in an IF-statement inside of `Foreach-Object`. How can I store my processes into `$processes` when the command is called inside of IF-Statement of the Foreach loop?

Comment: @SimpleThings I'm sorry totally missed these comments. I guess you were able to sort the questions above ?

Comment: No problem. No I have not sorted it out yet. I would really appreciate your help :).

Comment: So reg. the first question, why would the file not be written, if you are passing an outside variable containing the path where the file should be written to remember to use `$using:` so the Job sees that variable (aside from that I'm not sure what could be the possible reason) best advise would be to ask a new question with all details. `Wait-Job` will only influence your current thread, will block your current thread until the jobs are completed. Does not influence the logic inside your Jobs.

Comment: Reg. the second question, about the `If` statement, can you edit your question showing the code you're using? @SimpleThings

Comment: I have actually edited both the 1st and 2nd questions. Reg. the 1st question: I have used `$using:` since the beginning as you suggested. Please see my edited post.